# Relationship between electromagnetic and topological invariant

Tags: electromagnetism, gauss, topology

I read 17 equations that changed the world by Ian Stewart.  This book provides information about the correlation between  electromagnetic force and topological invariant.

> The idea of a topological invariant goes back to Gauss’s work on magnetism. He was interested in how magnetic and electrical field lines could link with each other, and he defined the linking number, which counts how many times one
> field line winds round another. This is a topological invariant: it remains the
> same if the curves are continuously deformed. He found a formula for this
> number using integral calculus, and every so often he expressed a wish for a
> better understanding of the ‘basic geometric properties’ of diagrams. It is no
> coincidence that the first serious inroads into such an understanding came
> through the work of one of Gauss’s students, Johann Listing, and Gauss’s
> assistant August Möbius. Listing’s Vorstudien zur Topologie (‘Studies in
> Topology’) of 1847 introduced the word ‘topology’, and Möbius made the role
> of continuous transformations explicit.

In the history of mathematics and science, was Gauss the first scholar to be interested in systematic topological invariants?  And how did Poincaré become interested in topological invariants?  Did Gauss' research enrich the general interest in topological invariants during Poincaré's era?

Comment: See [McTutor, History of Topology](https://mathshistory.st-andrews.ac.uk/HistTopics/Topology_in_mathematics), they assign the "first" to Lhuilier (1813), who was building on Euler's work. Gauss introduced the linking number in 1833 in a private diary, so he did not much influence anybody other than his students. [Poincare stated](https://mathshistory.st-andrews.ac.uk/Biographies/Poincare) that his own research in differential equations and multiple integrals led him to topology. There is little indication of Möbius's or Listing's influence, and he focused on different kinds of invariants.

Comment: @Conifold Thanks for your comment! I will read them!

Comment: @Conifold Can I ask one more thing? Under what circumstances did Poincaré ask questions that contributed to the birth of singular homology? I think that singular homology could also appear because there were some mathematical flaws or problems in Poincaré's era.

Comment: There is a detailed historical account in [Dieudonné, History of Algebraic and Differential Topology](https://www.google.com/books/edition/A_History_of_Algebraic_and_Differential/RUV5Dz90rDkC?hl=en&gbpv=0). Chapter I is about the work of Poincare, and yes, it is often described as somewhat non-rigorous. He generated a lot of ideas and methods leaving technical details to future generations and focused on smooth manifolds. Chapter II is about his successors and singular homology was introduced by one of them, Alexander, in 1915, who referred to the subject by Poincare's name *Analysis Situs*.

Comment: @Conifold Thanks for your reply! I will refer to it!!